# How to execute a makefile command when there is something else than.c files in a diectory?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

So basically I want to have a warning to the user when in the "Code" directory there is something else than C files, and I can't find anything relevant. Any leads?
This is my current code (not working):

```
ifneq ("$(shell ls Code -I "*.c")","")
  ls Code -I "*.c"
  @echo "test"
else
  @echo "test2"
endif
```

Comment: You need to be more specific: what is "not working" about your current setup?

Comment: It outputs "test" whether or not there is something else than c files in the directory

Comment: It looks like you try to list the non-matching files if they're found. What filenames are in that list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just:

```
extras := $(filter-out %.c,$(wildcard Code/*))
ifneq (,$(extras))
$(warn Extra files: $(extras))
endif
```

Comment: Oh that works thanks a lot, I was not aware that the filter-out function existed

Comment: See: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Functions.html and perhaps in particular this section: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html